# Escaped characters appearing when appending to HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, escaping

I am fetching HTML code via an AJAX call, and then **appending the code it to an existing HTML element**.
Problem is, the **appended code contains escaped characters, causing the HTML to break**, and resulting in haphazard elements looking like this: `Contact Us ▸<\/a><\/li>\n`:
[image: Contact Us ▸</a></li>\n]

The HTML element is: `<li class="listitems"><a href="https:\/\/website.com\/contact" class="listlinks">Contact Us ▸&lt;\/a&gt;&lt;\/li&gt;\n</a></li>`

For reference, the ajax response received is:

```
"<li class='listitems'><a href='https:\/\/website.com\/contact' class='listlinks'>Contact Us &rtrif;<\/a><\/li>\n"
```

And the JavaScript code used to add this to the existing `ul` element is:

```
let r = httpRequest.responseText; // The AJAX response
document.getElementById('mylist').insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",r);
```

I've also tried using the following:

```
let r = httpRequest.responseText; // The AJAX response
document.getElementById('mylist').interHTML += r;
```

but am observing the same results.

However, when I try either JavaScript code **in the browser's console: I get the expected results**: Contact Us ▸[image: Contact Us ▸]

And the HTML element is: `<li class="listitems"><a href="https://website.com/contact" class="listlinks">Contact Us ▸</a></li>`

I am unable to understand **why the code is not being unescaped and evaluated as HTML normally, but it works when I do it manually using the browser's console window**.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here and how I can fix this?

Comment: Are escape characters needed? If it is just a regular slash in quotes, escape characters arent needed. Correct me if im missing something.

Comment: Looks like improper handling of data on the server side and should be fixed there.

Comment: @Jack Lankford The AJAX response already is already escaped. Now, I want to add this HTML code but it breaks due to the escaped characters. But if I add it manually using the console, it is unescaped and code is added as expected.

Comment: @gre_gor The server sends out the data after `json_encode`ing it. While I could certainly change that, I want to understand why this issue occurs?

Comment: You have not shown any code, so we don't what are you actually doing. Provide a [mre].

Comment: Why are you even JSON encoding that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is JSON, you need to parse it.

```js
let responseText = `"<li class='listitems'><a href='https:\\/\\/website.com\\/contact' class='listlinks'>Contact Us &rtrif;<\\/a><\\/li>\\n"`;
let r = JSON.parse(responseText);
document.getElementById('mylist').insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",r);
```

```html
<ul id="mylist">
</ul>
```

Comment: Nope, that won't work. Results in `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: The double quotes are part of the JSON.

Comment: Thanks for editing with the working solution. Accepted as answer.

Comment: Damn. I tried that without the literals and failed so I just used regex

Comment: You cheated. There was not a double \\ on the n

Comment: @mplungjan I had to do that to turn the returned data into a literal for the snippet.

Comment: I know, But then OP needs to be told that his string is not valid JSON to begin with without the \\n

Comment: In the real script it's valid JSON coming from the server. It's necessary to escape backslashes to create JSON by hand here.

Comment: Agree with @mplungjan here. `json_encode` from the server isn't return escaped `\n`.  Hence, `JSON.parse` won't work @Barmar. Unmarking this as answer. Workaround is to not `json_encode` in the server. Root cause and solution still unknown.

Comment: The `\n` is not escaped in the JSON. But I need to escape it to create the equivalent value in a string literal here. It's just for the example, because I can't write an AJAX call here.

Comment: `\/` in the response is surely coming from `json_encode()` in the server.